# Problema ao atualizar ListActivity usando um adaptador customizado

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estou trabalhando em um aplicativo onde populo uma `ListActivity` usando dados de um `SQLite` criado pelo próprio programa. Ao adicionar itens no banco, a lista é atualizada automaticamente, porém ao remover, a lista não é atualizada.

Faço a inserção de itens novos numa `Activity` separada da principal, porém na hora de apagar itens, faço o mesmo dentro de um `DialogFragment` chamado de dentro da `ListActivity`. Eis meu código:

```
package activities;

import adapters.ItemListAdapter;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import br.bravosix.historico.R;
import classes.Database;
import classes.ListItem;
import fragments.QuickViewFragment;

public class ActivityList extends ListActivity {

    ItemListAdapter adapter;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // carrega os itens salvos no banco de dados quando
        // a tela é criada
        loadItems();
    }

    // re-carrega os itens após o resumo da activity

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadItems();
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list_items, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.menu_list_add) {
            // activity responsável por adicionar novos itens
            // ao banco de dados
            Intent addItem = new Intent(this, ActivityNewItem.class);
            startActivity(addItem);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ListItem item = (ListItem) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        QuickViewFragment quickView = QuickViewFragment.newInstance(item);
        quickView.show(fm, "tag_quick_view");
        // testei o notifyDataSetChanged aqui e não funcionou, o mesmo
        // ocorreu quando usei a função loadItems();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void loadItems() {
        Database db = new Database(this);
        adapter = new ItemListAdapter(this, db.readItems());
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

O que eu preciso fazer para que, quando o `QuickViewFragment` seja fechado, a lista seja atualizada?

Comment: Essa inserção de itens novos em outra activity, por acaso não poderia ser feita a adição de itens novos em `Dialog Fragment`?

Comment: É indiferente, no caso. É um aplicativo para uso pessoal e não precisa ser muito complexo. Criei uma Activity nova por comodidade, mas poderia perfeitamente ser algo semelhante a maneira que estou usando para ver/apagar os itens. Mas, o por que da pergunta?

Comment: O porque da pergunta é que se for um item simples, por exemplo um nome, você poderia fazer assim: um list fragment que utiliza loaders. Nessa lista você tem um menu para adicionar. Se você clicar em adicionar abre um dialog fragment pedindo o nome, você insere e a lista é atualizada automaticamente devido a você estar utilizando loaders. Se você pressionar um item, exibe um dialog dando opção de editar e deletar. E também é atualizado automaticamente devido ao uso de loaders. Acho assim bem mais simples quando a lista é simples.

Comment: O item no caso é um formulário, com 5 campos diferentes. Mas como funcionam os loaders? Tem algum link de referência?

Comment: Tenho sim mas é em inglês, serve?

Comment: Pode ser, sem problema algum.

Comment: [Documentação Oficial sobre Loaders][1]

[Documentação do site traduzida][2]

[Eu aprendi com este site sobre loaders][3]


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html
  [2]: http://celeiroandroid.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/loaders.html
  [3]: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

Comment: Mais uma coisa, tenha preferências por fragments, depois que usar e acostumar não irá querer outra coisa. Vi que está usando ListActivity.

Comment: Achei que seria mais simples usar uma ListActivity no lugar de um ListFragment por questões de o aplicativo ser para uso pessoal. Em outros projetos, uso mais o ListFragment pela simplicidade que os Fragments trouxeram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou sugerir uma solução para o problema do `Fragment` porém tenho outra sugestão para melhorar a forma como você atualiza sua lista na `ActivityList`.

Pelo que entendi, você atualiza a lista sempre que sua `Activity` é resumida, isso inclui a chamada ao `onResume` decorrente da finalização da `ActivityNewItem`, mas há um efeito negativo nessa forma devido ao ciclo de vida da `Activity`. Quando o seu app for pra segundo plano e voltar, você irá ao `BD` sem precisar.

No caso do `Fragment` não há interferência no ciclo de vida da `Activity` então o `onResume` não é chamado. E também não adianta chamar o `notifyDataSetChanged` porque naquele momento o `Fragment` vai ser exibido, e o usuário ainda não excluiu o item, dada a assíncronicidade.

---

### 1. Atualizando a lista após iteração com o QuickViewFragment

No método `onListItemClick`, eu faria uma pequena alteração. Passe um `Listener` para o Fragment (ou deixe o `onAttach` setá-lo), para que ao final da interação (update, delete, qualquer outra), ele chame o método para atualizar a lista.

O `ActionListener` no código, é a forma de comunicação (evitando acoplamento) entre o `Fragment` e a `Activity`. Com os métodos da interface o `Fragment` pode notificar a `Activity` das interações feitas que necessitam de atualização na `Activity`.

Ficaria algo como:

Classe `ActivityList`:

```
public class ActivityList extends ListActivity implements QuickViewFragment.ActionListener {

// ... Codigo e mais codigo

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ListItem item = (ListItem) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        QuickViewFragment quickView = QuickViewFragment.newInstance(item);
        quickView.setActionListener(this);
        // Sendo generico, pois nao sei que acoes poderiam ocorrer no fragment 
        quickView.show(fm, "tag_quick_view");
        // Nao precisa do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Item item) {
        atualizaLista(item);
        // O metodo atualiza pode ser de duas formas:
        // Ou ele remove o item da lista, sem ir no banco.
        // Ou ele atualiza toda a lista, select no banco.
    }

    // Demais metodos da interface

}
```

Classe `QuickViewFragment`:

```
public class QuickViewFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private ActionListener mAl;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(...) {
        // ...
    }

    public interface ActionListener {
        public void onDelete(...);
        public void onUpdate(...);
        // ... O que mais quiser
    }

    private void ActionListener al; // Getter/Setter suprimidos

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);

        if(a instanceof ActionListener) {
            mAl = (ActionListener) a;
        }

        // Apenas uma sugestão de uso, nao precisa ser assim...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if(al != null) {
            //Chamar alguma acao do Listener
        }

        super.onDismiss(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView(...) {
        al = null; // Evitar MemoryLeak
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ... Código

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // ... Mais Código

        // Na configuracao do botao negativo (utilizar o ClickListener para chamar a Callback.
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.quickview_delete,
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Codigo de deleção no BD...
                    if(mAl != null) {
                        mAl.onDelete(...);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Nos metódos da interface você atualizaria a sua lista.

O método `onAttach` pertence ao ciclo de vida do `Fragment`, Ele é chamado quando o `Fragment` é "attachado" na `Activity`, antes de ser adicionado. Recomendo a leitura da documentação sobre o [ciclo de vida do `Fragment`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle).

Já o método `onDismiss` é chamado quando o `Dialog` do `DialogFragment` esta sendo fechado. De uma olhada na documentação do método [`DialogFragment.onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#onDismiss%28android.content.DialogInterface%29).

### 2. Atualizando a lista após retorno da ActivityNewItem

Quando você chama uma activity usando `Intent`, existe uma forma alternativa que indica que você está esperando um resultado do retorno da `ActivityNewItem`. O `startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`, e para obter o retorno você precisa sobreescrever o método `onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` da sua `ListActivity` para saber se deve ou não atualizar a lista.

No método `onOptionsItemSelected` da `ListActivity` eu faria uma pequena alteração:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.menu_list_add) {
        // activity responsável por adicionar novos itens
        // ao banco de dados
        Intent addItem = new Intent(this, ActivityNewItem.class);
        startActivityForResult(addItem, 999, null); // Guarde o numero 999 pra depois
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

E adicionaria este método da classe `ListActivity`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode /* 999 */, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == 999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Atualiza lista, pois o retorno foi positivo...
    }

    super.onActivityResult(...);
}
```

Na `ActivityNewItem` coloque algo como:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    if(houveAlteracao) { // Se houve alguma atualizacao nessa `Activity`
        setResult(RESULT_OK, dado);
        // Diz para a Activity que me chamou
        // Que houve uma alteracao de dados aqui...
    }

    super.finish();
}
```

Acredito que com isso funcionando, você não precise usar o método `onResume` para atualizar a lista, salvo se algum app externo modifique seu `BD`.

A resposta foi longa, mas espero que ajude...

Comment: Estou tendo um problema na hora de utilizar as interfaces. Não sei muito bem como trabalhar com elas ainda. Recebi o seguinte erro: http://pastebin.com/0hb6VBtP Como resolvo isso? E como eu chamo as funções da interface dentro dos botões do fragment? No caso, tenho três botões: um para apagar o item, um para enviá-lo por email (ainda não implementado) e um terceiro que serve apenas para fechar a tela.

Comment: Ah, esse erro é culpa minha, é que no método `onAttach`, esqueci que precisa chamar o super. Vou incorporar isso na resposta. Além disso vou incluir exemplos de chamadas das callbacks.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk, adicionei coisa no `onCreateView` e o método `onClick` (decorrente do click no botão de deleção)

Comment: obrigado pelas mudanças, mas acho que não servirão. esqueci de comentar que estou usando a classe `AlertDialog` para construir meu `DialogFragment`, portanto preciso colocar a execução dos comandos dentro dos botões que a classe disponibiliza (`PositiveButton`, `NegativeButton` e `NeutralButton`). Como posso atribuir as funções a esses botões? Desculpe por esquecer disto!

Comment: Hmm, essa informação é nova, irei dar uma olhada e atualizo. Poderia incluir o codigo de construção do dialog?

Comment: Claro, sem problemas. Já estava preparando para postá-lo. Eis o código do `QuickViewFragment`: http://pastebin.com/f4TRTTZs Se precisar de mais algo, por gentileza me avise que eu disponibilizo imediatamente. Edit: já estava, inclusive, incluindo os códigos que me indicou quando empaquei nessa questão do comentário anterior.

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk, adicionei o uso no Listener do botão negativo, onde você deleta o Item

Comment: Ok, acho que eu entendi então. Devo colocar o código que apaga o item dentro do procedimento onDelete, certo? Após isso, coloco o código que atualiza a lista no método da interface? Apenas isso ainda ficou meio confuso. E qual é a finalidade do método onAttach e do onDismiss? Pode me apontar algum link onde possa ler mais sobre?

Comment: @gh0st_h4wk, não precisa migrar o código de deleção pro `onDelete`, pode até ser. Mas o método `onDelete` na `Activity` seria para atualizar a lista, pode até migrar a deleção para lá. Irei comentar sobre o `onAttach` e o `onDismiss` na resposta.